# running jupyter on hortonworks

Tags: apache-spark, ipython, jupyter-notebook, hortonworks-sandbox

I installed the Jupyter notebook in hortonworks following the tutorial available on their website.
link "https://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/using-ipython-notebook-with-apache-spark/"

When i got done with the installation, i ran the script using jupyter notebook --allow-root

No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
[C 20:34:30.227 NotebookApp]

```
Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
to login with a token:
    http://localhost:8889/?token=12b43fa62df699d6e136967e3a74d2d0260ff2937df9b49a
```

I copied the url into my browser, and i keep getting server not found.

I forwarded the port and all, but nothing seems to work.

This is my values for ipython

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                             
source /opt/rh/python27/enable
IPYTHON_OPTS="notebook --port 8889 \                                                                                    
--notebook-dir='/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/' \                                                                       
--ip='*' --no-browser" pyspark
```

Any help on how to get this working please? Thanks

Comment: Did you run jupyter notebook on cluster? If yes then follow the above [link] 
 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51869574/what-is-the-use-of-jupyter-notebook-cluster)  for using it outside headnode.