# What is the use of Jupyter Notebook cluster

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, cluster-computing, jupyter

Can you tell me what is the use of jupyter cluster. I created jupyter cluster,and established its connection.But still I'm confused,how to use this cluster effectively?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Jupyter Notebook cluster, you can run notebook on the local machine and connect to the notebook on the cluster by setting the appropriate port number. Example code:

1. Go to Server using `ssh username@ip_address` to server.
2. Set up the port number for running notebook. On remote terminal run  `jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=7800`
3. On your local terminal `run ssh -N -f -L localhost:8001:localhost:7800 username@ip_address` of server.
4. Open web browser on local machine and go to `http://localhost:8001/`

Comment: When you use jupyter notebook without cluster your code will get execute on local cpu/gpu. But when you use notebook cluster code will get execute on server cpu/gpu.

Comment: Will this make use of all the cluster system resources like RAM., and use to process efficiently like hadoop? Will it do so?

Comment: I am interested too, if jupyter can run jobs distributed or not. In the latter case it would still run jobs on single node, even if is connected to a cluster. Right?