# How to access headnode hdfs files via jupyter notebook

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, hdfs, cluster-computing

I have set up a head node cluster.I successfully integrated a jupyter notebook with it.([Using this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51869574/what-is-the-use-of-jupyter-notebook-cluster))

I am also sucessfully able to run pyspark.I referred this [link](https://blog.sicara.com/get-started-pyspark-jupyter-guide-tutorial-ae2fe84f594f) for that

Now I want to access hdfs files in headnode via jupyter notebook.But when I run the below command which fetches data from hdfs.

```
df = sqlContext.read.json('hdfs:///192.168.21.110/user/hdfs/ML/pass/Teleram_18/notefind/2018-12-14/')
```

I get the following error

```
An error occurred while calling o29.json.
: java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs:///192.168.21.110/user/hdfs/ML/pass/Teleram_18/notefind/2018-12-14/
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:705)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$15.apply(DataSource.scala:389)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$15.apply(DataSource.scala:389)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:397)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What is actually wrong? One thing I noticed is that I have pyspark installed on both user head node and hdfs user head node.And I use jupyter notebook using user headnode.

I submit application programs in hdfs headnode and I am able to access hdfs files inside hdfs user spark shell.What can I do so that I can access hdfs files from normal headnode user.There is nothing wrong with my path, I can find the data using hadoop fs

**UPDATE** : I see that in normal user mode python3.5 and pyspark 2.4 is used whereas in hdfs user python2.7 and pyspark 2.3.1 is used.How can I resolve this

Comment: why do you have three slashes after hdfs? shouldn't it be just 2 slashes?

Comment: I have tried both, Some of the answers in different sources asked me to put three slashes.so just tried

Comment: did you also try without the hdfs and ip address, just the location path?

Comment: Yes I did try both.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with port, for example

```
hdfs://192.168.21.110:9000/user/hdfs/ML/pass/Teleram_18/notefind/2018-12-14/
```

Port 9000 - You can verify this port in `core-site.xml`.