# How can I know and change the port number in Jupyter in REPL of julia?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to use Jupyter notebook in HPC. Then, I am following two instructions as below:

- https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/jupyter-notebooks/remote-jupyter-notebook/
- [What is the use of Jupyter Notebook cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51869574/what-is-the-use-of-jupyter-notebook-cluster)

But in our HPC, `jupyter` is not installed.

```
# In HPC
$ jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=7800
-bash: jupyter: command not found
```

So, I installed `IJulia` in Julia in HPC as below:

```
# In HPC
$ julia
julia> ]add IJulia
julia> using IJulia
julia> notebook()
```

But in that way to run Jupyter notebook, how can I know or modify the port number?